# How to disable firefox "new tab" action when pressin ctrl and clicking a link with javascript event?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a javascript function call on a hyperlink with CTRL lookup function (operation is different when ctrl is pressed). Everything works great with IE and CHROME, but when using the code with firefox it opens a new tab and tries to open a page called "javascript:function();"...

How to avoid this to happen?

Comment: by changing your keybindings. It's not nice to hijack established key shortcuts. Chrome will happily open a link in a new tab with ctrl-click, so if you turn that off you're ruining people's way of using their browser. Not cool.

Comment: This functionality was created for resource calendar item-multiselect operation and not for regular links on webpage.

Comment: then you should not be using `<a>` elements, which in HTML5 are for page navigation and page navigation *only*. Put the click handling on the div/span/whatevers containing the links, and leave the links themselves alone so that ctrl-click still opens the navigation instruction in a new tab/window? Fairly old question by now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is the default browser action. You can prevent it by calling [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault):

```
element.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //do stuff
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/okoRorU/1/edit)

---

Also, anchors (`<a>`) may not be the best suited element for your use case. You could also use `<span>` elements (which have no default browser action associated with click events) and style them.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the <a> tag and moved the function call to "onClick" event and now this Works!

Comment: It does not work on right click and open in new tab.. any ideas?

Comment: @DilipRajkumar right-click opens a context menu. You can't prevent actions selected from the context menu, but you could prevent the user from opening the context menu entirely by listening to the `contextmenu` event and preventing it, but that is usually regarded as a bad accessibility and usability practice if you don't provide a context menu replacement. In the general use case, if you really don't want the `<a>` element to behave as a link, it is easier to use a `<span>` and hook your JavaScript to it instead. That way the user will not have an "open in new tab" option in its context menu.

Comment: Thank you @FabrícioMatté , I finally resolved by stating as browser behavior..:)